What is the correct way to scale this SVG?
I have e.g. this SVG:


<svg><rect width="6" height="14" x="1" y="4" fill="currentColor"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade0" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="0;svgSpinnersBarsFade1.end-0.25s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="9" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".4"><animate fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.15s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="17" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".3"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade1" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.3s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect></svg>



How can I scale it? I have tried using width and height attributes on the <svg>, tried setting font-size in hopes of it reacting to that, tried setting a viewbox (which I still don't get how it works). I've also tried putting it in a container element and style it via width: 100%; height: 100%;. None of these attempts had any effect whatsoever.
Example:


svg { width: 100%; height: 100% }
<div style="width: 64px; height: 64px; background-color: #f8f8f8;">
  <svg height="64" width="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="font-size: 64px;"><rect width="6" height="14" x="1" y="4" fill="currentColor"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade0" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="0;svgSpinnersBarsFade1.end-0.25s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="9" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".4"><animate fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.15s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="17" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".3"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade1" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.3s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect></svg>
</div>



I'd love someone to not only provide a solution, but also explain the basics behind this, and why none of my approaches is valid.

it should be viewBox="0 0 24 24" for your case. It's all about a correct viewbox

Please don't edit questions to say an answer doesn't work. Edit the question to explain specifically what you want to happen. Then answers can be tailored to your exact requirements.

@TemaniAfif Then why does it work in Paulie_D's answer with a viewBox="0 0 64 64"?

it doesn't work, the SVG is not scaling (add border to the div element)

Answer updated with examples.

@TemaniAfif It's not scaling to the full width of the container, but it's much larger than in my attempts. I need to understand exactly what's going on.

because the width/height of his div is much bigger. It's scaling compared to your example but not scaling to the full div size

Then how do you scale to fit an SVG inside a container, without knowledge about the viewbox?

calculate it using getBoundingClientRect or getBBox

to allow your <rect> to scale according to the attribute <svg viewbox="0 0 X X"> value, use for width="6" height="14" x="1" y="4" percentage and not fixed values ...

As I mentioned in a removed edit, I'm getting these SVGs from a library, so I can't affect that.

sounds like the library isn't very good - the designers should have determined appropriate viewBoxes for you already. Maybe choose a different library.

Just remove the width/height etc. from the SVG and it will scale to the bounding container depending on the viewbox.
The viewbox defines the canvas dimensions for placement of the elements within. It has no relevance to the actual size of the SVG in the HTML.

The viewBox attribute defines the position and dimension, in user space, of an SVG viewport.
...
When an SVG contains a viewBox attribute (often in combination with a preserveAspectRatio attribute), a transform stretches or resizes the SVG viewport to fit a particular container element.

However, setting a width/height in the SVG will set the size until removed or overridden.


div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64"><rect width="6" height="14" x="1" y="4" fill="currentColor"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade0" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="0;svgSpinnersBarsFade1.end-0.25s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="9" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".4"><animate fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.15s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="17" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".3"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade1" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.3s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect></svg>
</div>



In your specific SVG, you aren't actually using the whole canvas as the objects you place on it are essentially only using the top left corner. If you change the viewbox so they fill the SVG it looks quite different.


div {
  width: 100px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64"><rect width="6" height="14" x="1" y="4" fill="currentColor"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade0" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="0;svgSpinnersBarsFade1.end-0.25s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="9" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".4"><animate fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.15s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="17" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".3"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade1" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.3s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect></svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><rect width="6" height="14" x="1" y="4" fill="currentColor"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade0" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="0;svgSpinnersBarsFade1.end-0.25s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="9" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".4"><animate fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.15s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect><rect width="6" height="14" x="17" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".3"><animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade1" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.3s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate></rect></svg>
</div>




Does that mean I can remove the viewBox? I'm getting these icons from a library, so I don't want to touch the content of the svg element.

No, it's an essential component that defines the canvas you are painting the elements on.

So I should always set the viewBox to 0 0 ${size} ${size}?

As a rough generalization, yes. As I said, it defines the space you have to work with when sizing and positioning the objects in the SVG

So without me knowing the correct viewbox, there's no way to tell an SVG like the one provided to fill its container?

you can calculate the viewBox using javascript i.e. just get the bounding box of whatever you want to display and set the viewBox to that.

That seems ridiculous in a format designed to be scalable, even carrying the term in its very name.

Yes it is, the library designers should have done that for you. That's a library problem, not an SVG problem. The tools are there they just need to be used properly.

FYI, the "default" viewBox is viewBox="0 0 300 150"
without a viewBox, the SVG gets a 300 x 150 pixel size in the HTML document
with a viewBox the SVG sizes to its container
For sanity, always use a viewBox
Libraries that set width and heigth attributes on a SVG should be burnt,
its like using !important in CSS (IMHO)



<svg style="background:pink">
  <circle r="75" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="peru"/>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 300 150" style="background:pink;width:300;height:150">
  <circle r="75" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="silver"/>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 300 150" style="background:pink">
  <circle r="75" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="gold"/>
</svg>



Those id values in your SVG animation will get you in trouble when more SVGs use the same id
And since I know you love Web Components as much as I do;
this one makes it easier to play with values
Note the viewBox y value. the viewBox "shifts" upward so the rect does NOT need an y=2 value since the default is y=0


customElements.define("svg-bars", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback() {
    this.style.display = "inline-block";
    this.style.verticalAlign = "top";
    let fill = this.getAttribute("fill") || "currentColor";
    this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 -2 12 12" style="background:pink">` +
    [2,5,8].map((x,i)=>`<rect width=2 height=8 x=${x} fill=${fill}>`+
      `<animate repeatCount=indefinite attributeName=opacity begin=${i*.15} dur=.75s values=1;.;1 />`+
      `</rect>`).join("") +
    `</svg>`
  }
})
<svg-bars></svg-bars>
<svg-bars fill=red></svg-bars>
 
<style>
  svg-bars { width:150px } 
</style>




You may be missing a point: SVGs can't be compared to raster/bitmap images or HTML elements.

Bitmap images have clearly defined intrinsic image dimensions based on the pixel data (although highly abstracted due to compression algorithms) – SVGs don't.
Bitmap images don't have "off-canvas" pixels – SVGs may have invisible elements just because they are not within the viewBox.
HTML/CSS-styled elments have a plethora of "auto-content-fitting" concepts shrinking or expanding an element automatically to the size – SVGs don't

Simplified explanation of viewBox
You may think of it as a document size. In graphic applications like Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator, Indesign etc. you can specify an Artboard or document size like US-letter or DINA-4. You can place and arrange elements on this area.
When we change the document size some elements may become off-canvas so not visible – although they are still present in the document itself.
This analogy obviously has its issues:
We can't create a new document in a GUI based application without specifying a document size – in SVG we can – as we can also use relative units for "fluid" layouts (by no means on par with something like CSS flex).


body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
}

rect {
  fill: #ccc;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

circle {
  fill: #999;
}

.col {
  margin-bottom: 7em;
}
<div class="col">
  <h3>DIN A4 (210 &times; 297mm)</h3>
  <p>Viewbox matches content</p>
  <svg width="210" height="297" viewBox="0 0 210 297">
      <rect width="210" height="297"  />
      <circle cx="105" cy="280" r="10" />
    </svg>

</div>

<div class="col">
  <h3>DIN A5 (148.5 &times; 210mm)</h3>
  <p>Clipped/off-canvas elements: viewBox doesn't match content</p>
  <svg width="148.5" height="210" viewBox="0 0 148.5 210">
      <rect width="210" height="297"  />
      <circle cx="105" cy="280" r="10" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <h3>DIN A5 (148.5 &times; 210mm)</h3>
  <p>Viewbox matches content (A4 document scaled in layout)</p>

  <svg width="148.5" height="210" viewBox="0 0 210 297">
      <rect width="210" height="297" />
      <circle cx="105" cy="280" r="10" />
    </svg>
</div>


<div class="col">
  <h3>DIN A4-landscape (297 &times; 210mm)</h3>
  <p>No Viewbox – fluid design based on relative units</p>

  <svg width="297" height="210">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
      <circle cx="50%" cy="90%" r="5%" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <h3>Fluid design: resizable</h3>
  <p>No Viewbox – fluid design based on relative units</p>

  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
      <circle cx="50%" cy="85%" r="10" />
    </svg>
</div>



Further reading about viewBox

"Mariana Beldi: 6 Common SVG Fails (and How to Fix Them)"
"Amelia Bellamy-Royds: How to Scale SVG"
"Sara Soueidan: Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations (Part 1) — The viewport, viewBox, and preserveAspectRatio"

Calculate suitable viewBox values
As mentioned before getBBox() helps.


const svg = document.querySelector('svg')
adjustViewBox(svg)

function adjustViewBox(svg) {
  let {
    x,
    y,
    width,
    height
  } = svg.getBBox();
  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [x, y, width, height].join(' '));
}
svg {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  width: 20vmin;
}
<svg>
  <rect width="6" height="14" x="1" y="4" fill="currentColor">
    <animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade0" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="0;svgSpinnersBarsFade1.end-0.25s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate>
  </rect>
  <rect width="6" height="14" x="9" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".4">
    <animate fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.15s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate>
  </rect>
  <rect width="6" height="14" x="17" y="4" fill="currentColor" opacity=".3">
    <animate id="svgSpinnersBarsFade1" fill="freeze" attributeName="opacity" begin="svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.3s" dur="0.75s" values="1;.2"></animate>
  </rect>
</svg>



Worth mentioning: getBBox() requires an element to be rendered.
So this (at first glance trivial) method can't easily be replicated in a headless/virtual DOM environment.
Also, getBBox() doesn't return the maximum expansion of an element, including animated resizing.
Improve assets/report issues

I'm getting these SVGs from a
library, so I can't affect that.

You should always file issues via bugtrackers or github issue reports.
If a library or the developers don't provide a bug reporting channel, that's a pretty good reason to avoid using it and search for alternatives.
Take also inspiration from repos like this "SVG Spinners (CSS & SMIL)"
Apart from the missing viewBox the designers should have provided a way to implement the loading animations as <img> elements or CSS background-images by adding a xmlns namespace attribute. You won't be able to style any fill colors
but ... its just a looping loading animation - no need to inline it.


body {
  font-size: 20vmin;
}

.loading {
  width: 1em;
}

.loading-bg {
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-size: 1em;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect width='6' height='14' x='1' y='4' fill='currentColor'><animate id='svgSpinnersBarsFade0' fill='freeze' attributeName='opacity' begin='0;svgSpinnersBarsFade1.end-0.25s' dur='0.75s' values='1;.2'/></rect><rect width='6' height='14' x='9' y='4' fill='currentColor' opacity='.4'><animate fill='freeze' attributeName='opacity' begin='svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.15s' dur='0.75s' values='1;.2'/></rect><rect width='6' height='14' x='17' y='4' fill='currentColor' opacity='.3'><animate id='svgSpinnersBarsFade1' fill='freeze' attributeName='opacity' begin='svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.3s' dur='0.75s' values='1;.2'/></rect></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<img class="loading" src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect width='6' height='14' x='1' y='4' fill='currentColor'><animate id='svgSpinnersBarsFade0' fill='freeze' attributeName='opacity' begin='0;svgSpinnersBarsFade1.end-0.25s' dur='0.75s' values='1;.2'/></rect><rect width='6' height='14' x='9' y='4' fill='currentColor' opacity='.4'><animate fill='freeze' attributeName='opacity' begin='svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.15s' dur='0.75s' values='1;.2'/></rect><rect width='6' height='14' x='17' y='4' fill='currentColor' opacity='.3'><animate id='svgSpinnersBarsFade1' fill='freeze' attributeName='opacity' begin='svgSpinnersBarsFade0.begin+0.3s' dur='0.75s' values='1;.2'/></rect></svg>">

<div class="loading-bg"></div>



